# Phonegap JQuery Mobile m-commerce application

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, paypal, e-commerce, cordova

I am making a Mobile App combining *jQuery Mobile* and *phonegap*.

I have a database of products which the user can browse also from a normal e-commerce website.

But I am also making a mobile application so the user can browse the same catalog of products, and also make a purchase in the app.

But how to implement the actual purchase. Is there any plugins such as *Paypal*, or other services that offer payment solution through `phonegap`.

Any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PayPal just released a [PhoneGap plugin for Android and iOS](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin).

Comment: Do you know if is there any examples, except the ones in their GitHub ones, more complete maybe?

Comment: The only other one I know of is https://www.paypal-labs.com/devblog/phonegap-android-sdk-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

In Git may paypal phonegap plugins are available but i suggest you go with native approach to maintain security and reduce/avoide memory leaks

Answer (score 0):

paypal was given by phonegap plugin
use this link .https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin